# Authcache will cache user menu

Tags: 7, caching

I have used [Authcache](http://drupal.org/project/authcache) and memcache to cache pages for authenticated users.

However, I have a user specific menu displayed at top right of every page, and the menu sometimes displayed a wrong users' infomation (avartar, username).

I have checked the **Authcache** *Retrieve menu title using Ajax or ESI* option at every menu entry's config page.

I also have tried to generate the menu items in code, but both with no good.

Answer (score 0):

If you serve your menus as blocks then you can use Authcache Block sub module. On the block admin page you will find an Authcache personalization setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I cannot set the username as the menu title, so I changed the menu title in code. Also the user pic is rendered in code, and how to personalize this?

Comment: `<?php 
       print theme('user_picture__nav_bar', array(
        'account' => $user,
       ));`
      ?>

Comment: The easy way is to design your custom menu through Views and expose it as a block.